# Change going forward and backward when searching for a character in a line

Tags: vim

When I use vim to find a letter in a line I use the `f` key and then to repeat the motion forward I have to use `;` and to repeat the motion backwards I have to use `,`. However, I would like to do change this and go forwards with `,` and backwards with `;`. What exactly would I have to put in my `vimrc`?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl, I tried to find how to do this on stackoverflow

Comment: That's not enough to make it a programming question, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put anything in your `.vimrc`; this already exists. You may need to change the way you search for characters though.

If you use <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> to search for characters, <kbd>;</kbd> goes forward, while <kbd>,</kbd> goes backwards.

However…

If you use <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> to search for characters, <kbd>,</kbd> goes forward, while <kbd>;</kbd> goes backwards.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Igbanam, however I am not really wanting to use this solution since i need to press `shift+f` and `shift+t` which I would prefer using just `f` and `t`. Of course I could inverse both of these but I would prefer just swapping `;` and `,`. However, I think it is more than just doing inoremap since I have to specify to swap `,` and `;` just in the context when I clicked `f` or `t`.